# В magento создал учетную запись клиента через админку. Пытаюсь войти на сайт, не пускает "Неверный email или пароль. "

Tags: php, cms, magento

Если регистрируюсь (создаю учетную запись) через сайт то все впорядке, входит и выходит без проблем. 
Кто сталкивался есть решение проблемы?
Адрес и пароль верны, проверял многократно. 
magento CE 1.9.1.0

[image: сравнение учеток]

Answer (score 3):

Копия [ответа с Mail.ru](http://otvet.mail.ru/answer/1759274152):

> При создании через административный интерфейс учётной записи клиента интернет-магазина надо правильно заполнять самую верхнюю графу (она у Вас выделена жёлтым).
>   В этой графе указывается, к какому интернет-магазину будет привязан клиент.
>
> Magento позволяет из единого административного интерфейса управлять сразу нескольки интернет-магазинами, причём в каждом из таких магазинов может вестись свой, отдельный от остальных магазинов учёт клиентов и товаров.
>
> При создании через административный интерфейс учётной записи клиента значением по-умолчанию указанной верхней графы почему-то является административная витрина.
>   Практического смысла в этом мало, и это, видимо, недоработка Magento Community Edition.
>
> Вместо административной витрины там надо указать интернет-магазин, и тогда созданная учётная запись станет доступна для авторизации с витрины выбранного магазина.